# Security.System.Exception in ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Could somebody help me with this problem please??
[Message Exception Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY5u8.png)

I've tried adding `<trust level="Full"/>`  on the Web.config file but still doesn't work

Comment: Do you manage the server? Or is this a 3rd hosted server? Please put the error details in your question as text. An image is fine to supplement your post with, but the essential details need to be directly in the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign Network Service read permission on the EventLog/Security key

1)Open the Registry Editor:

-Select Start then Run

-Enter regedt32 or regedit

2)Navigate/expand to the following key:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security
```

3)Right-click on this entry and select Permissions

4)Add the Network Service user

5)Give it Read permission